# Subtrair Datas MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Eu quero deletar da tabela usuarios com mesmo nome,porém so aqueles que a diferença da Data do banco de dados e da data atual(na hora do select) forem por exemplo,menor que 5 minutos.

A estrutura do meu banco de dados é :

```
Login | Nome  |        Hora 

    0       joao    2015-05-30 12:05:06
    1       joao    2015-05-30 12:13:06
    2       joao    2015-05-30 12:07:06
```

Como a subtração das datas entre Login 0 e Login 2 da 2 minutos,logo ele deletaria o mais recente,que é o login 2.

Estou usando a seguinte Query para deletar nomes iguais :

```
DELETE a FROM tabela AS a, tabela AS b WHERE a.nome=b.nome AND a.login < b.login
```

Estou usando MYSQL ,obrigado !

Comment: Se essa é a tua tabela, qual seria o resultado que queres obter?

Comment: então,eu quero que ele delete os nomes iguais,somente se a data atual - a data no banco de dados forem menor que 5 minutos. se tiverem 5 nomes iguais,porém um deles tiver com diferença de 2 minutos pro outro,deletar ele.a diferença entre as datas tem que ser maior que 5 minutos

Comment: E o Login1? Porque é que não é apagado? É mais recente que o Login2 não?

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta assim

```
delete t1 
from tabela t1 
inner join (
   select nome, count(nome)
   from tabela
   group by nome
   having (count(nome) >= 2) 
) as x
on x.nome = t1.nome
where date_add(t1.hora,interval 5 minute) > now();
```

Esta query elimina da tabela os registos com o mesmo nome se a diferença entre a data na tabela (coluna Hora) e a data actual (curtime()) for menor que 5 minutos.

Comment: olá,ele está deletando aonde for menor que 5 minutos,porém ele ta setando a hora depoiis para a mesma que a atual.Por exemplo :
2015-05-30 21:58:20
2015-05-30 21:30:20
quando ele não deleta,ele altera a hora ,ficando :
2015-05-30 21:58:20
2015-05-30 21:58:20
Ou seja,aonde não for menor que 5 minutos,ele seta pra mesma hora que foi executa a query.Obrigado

Comment: Então necessitas de, após executar o delete, executar uma instrução de update para actualizar a hora dos registos que não foram eliminados.

Comment: vou explicar pra que preciso:
Tenho um programa java com leitor biométrico,e toda hora que alguem poi o dedo,ele envia pro banco de dados o nome da pessoa e a hora.
porém,ele envia várias vezes seguidas.Como não consegui resolver pelo java,então vou corrigir na hora da inserção.
então,quando ele enviasse o nome e a hora,caso tenha o mesmo nome e uma hora com diferença de segundos,ele excluisse a mais antiga e deixasse a nova.
Ele não excluiria apenas se a hora que ele fez a inserção fosse maior que 5 minutos da atual,então ele deixaria.Obrigado por continuar me ajudando !

Comment: O link do código da inserção e delete:
http://pastebin.com/SyVN9fBp

Comment: Mas não é isso que a query faz? Apenas precisas de limitar para que apenas sejam apagados os registos para o utilizador que acabou de colocar o dedo no leitor.
delete.... where date_add(t1.hora,interval 5 minute) > now() and nome = $nomee;
Depois podes fazer um insert normal como estas a fazer no teu exemplo http://pastebin.com/SyVN9fBp

Comment: Te amo Cara,fiz uns pequenos ajustes e funcionou !!

Comment: Ainda bem que funcionou :)